# transformClassesWithDexForDebug using IndoorAtlas Library

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, dex

I try to use IndoorAtlas Android SDK example. I follow [this](http://docs.indooratlas.com/android/dev-guide/getting-user-location.html) guide.

But when I try to run it i get this error:

> Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object[] using a local variable of type com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IAGeofenceRequest. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
>
> Error:1 error; aborting
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/IndoorLocalization/app/libs/indooratlas-android-sdk-2.5.1.jar' to '/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/IndoorLocalization/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/10/indooratlas-android-sdk-2.5.1_dbe918a8d06cf55c975257e4802cd6d4f4f48ea4'

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add any details like code used, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndoorAtlas Android SDK 2.5.1 had a bug with proguard opimizations. Use the newer 2.5.2 version which has this bug fixed. Version 2.5.2 can be used by specifying

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.indooratlas.android:indooratlas-android-sdk:2.5.2'
    ...
}
```

in your applications build.gradle file.